# Authenticate and login script

Tags: php, authentication

How can I improve/secure my login script and how to check for any possible injection?

PS. the script must run on multiple platforms, so I need empty arrays for cases such as the Android ones.

### user_table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `user_table` (
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=63 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user_id | int(11) | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| user_type | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |

### student_table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `student_table` (
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`user_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`user_pass ` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user_id | int(11) | NO | PRI | NULL |  |
| user_type | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| user_email | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| user_pass | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |

### teacher_table:

```sql
 CREATE TABLE `teacher_table` (
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Class` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`DEPARTMENT` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`user_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`user_pass ` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user_id | int(11) | NO | PRI | NULL |  |
| Class | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| DEPARTMENT | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| user_email | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| user_pass | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |

### management_table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `management_table` (
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Class` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`DEPARTMENT` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`HEAD` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`user_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`user_pass ` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user_id | int(11) | NO | PRI | NULL |  |
| Class | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| DEPARTMENT | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| HEAD | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| user_email | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| user_pass | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |

### user_status table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `user_status` (
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Login_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_token` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`user_status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user_id | int(11) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| Login_id | int(11) | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| user_token | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| user_status | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |

### login script:

```
<?php

 //filter email var before connecting to database
 function validateEmail($email) {
  if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  //echo "email is valid";        
  }
   else {
   //echo "Email not valid";
   exit;
   }
 }
//connect to database
function db_connect($db_name, $db_username, $db_password) 
{
 $conn = new PDO($db_name, $db_username, $db_password);
 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
 return $conn; 
}
 // check login credentials 
function userLogin($email, $password,$PDO)
{
 $stmt = $PDO->prepare("
   SELECT student_table.user_id ,student_table.user_pass
   FROM student_table
   WHERE student_table.user_email = :EMAIL
   UNION 
   SELECT teacher_table.user_id ,teacher_table.user_pass
   FROM teacher_table
   WHERE teacher_table.user_email = :EMAIL
   UNION 
   SELECT management_table.user_id,management_table.user_pass
   FROM management_table
   WHERE management_table.user_email = :EMAIL");

 $stmt->bindParam(':EMAIL', $email);
 $stmt->execute();
 $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
 $hash = $row['user_pass'];             
 $returnApp = array( 'LOGIN' => 'Wrong_password_email');

 if (!empty($row) && password_verify($password, $hash)) 
 {
  $user_id = $row['user_id'];
  return $user_id;
 }else{
  return $returnApp;                 
  }
}
//guidv4
function guidv4($data = null) {
  $data = $data ?? random_bytes(16);
  assert(strlen($data) == 16);
  $data[6] = chr(ord($data[6]) & 0x0f | 0x40);
  $data[8] = chr(ord($data[8]) & 0x3f | 0x80);
  return vsprintf('%s%s-%s-%s-%s-%s%s%s', str_split(bin2hex($data), 4));
}
//create token
function createtoken($user_id,$user_online,$user_token,$PDO){

  $sql_insert = INSERT INTO user_status 
                (user_id, user_token,user_status) 
                VALUES 
                (:ID,:TOKEN,:ONLINE );

  $stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql_insert);
  $stmt->bindParam(':ID', $user_id);
  $stmt->bindParam(':ONLINE', $user_online);
  $stmt->bindParam(':TOKEN', $user_token);
     
 if ($stmt->execute()){
  
 }else{

 }
}
//getting user type
function usertype($user_id,$PDO){
  $sql_select ="SELECT user_table.user_type AS user
                FROM user_table 
                WHERE user_table.user_id = :USER_ID";
  $stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql_select);
  $stmt->bindParam(':USER_ID', $user_id);
                
  if ($stmt->execute()) {
     $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
     return $row;
  }else{                          
  }                         
}
//getting specific data for user limitation
function getdata($user_id,$PDO){

  $stmt = $PDO->prepare("
                     SELECT
                           student_table.user_type AS type,
                           user_status.login_id AS id,
                           user_status.user_token AS Token,
                           null,
                           null
                     FROM  student_table
                     LEFT JOIN user_status ON user_status.user_id = student_table.user_id
                     WHERE  student_table.user_id = :USERID
                     UNION 
                     SELECT
                           teacher_table.Class AS CL,
                           teacher_table.DEPARTMENT AS DEP,
                           user_status.login_id AS ID,
                           user_status.user_token AS TOKEN,
                           null 
                     FROM  teacher_table
                     LEFT JOIN user_status ON user_status.user_id = teacher_table.user_id
                     WHERE  teacher_table.user_id = :USERID 
                     UNION
                     SELECT
                           management_table.CLASS AS CL,
                           management_table.DEPARTMENT AS DEP,
                           management_table.HEAD AS HEAD,
                           user_status.login_id AS ID,
                           user_status.user_token AS TOKEN 
                     FROM  management_table
                     LEFT JOIN user_status ON user_status .user_id = management_table.user_id
                     WHERE  management_table.user_id = :USERID ");

$stmt->bindParam(':USERID', $user_id);
                
 if ($stmt->execute()) {
 $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
 $data = array( 'LOGIN' => 'Log_In_Success');
 $final = array_merge($data, $row);

 return $final;
                 
 }else{
                 
 }                         
}


 $email = $_POST['email'];

 //validate email 
 validateEmail($email);

// connect to data base
try 
{
 $PDO=db_connect("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DATABASE", "root", "");
 //echo "connection success";
}
 catch (PDOException $e) {
 //echo "Database error! " . $e->getMessage();
}

$password =$_POST['pass'];
//getting either user_id or email/pass dont match database
$result = userLogin($email,$password,$PDO); 
       
$user_online = 'ONLINE';
$user_token = guidv4();

//if checks if email/pass is correct or error
if (ctype_digit($result)) {
//create token
 $token = createtoken($result,$user_online,$user_token,$PDO);
//get type
 $user_type = usertype($result,$PDO);
// get data
 $data = getdata($result,$PDO);
// merge data with type
 $final = array_merge($data,$user_type);

 echo json_encode($final);

 }else{
  echo json_encode($result);
  exit;
 }
?>
```

Comment: Wasn't this code already posted for review? Didn't someone already tell you to improve the tabbing (the easiest editing technique to perform in software development)?

Comment: @mickmackusa yeah but this is the updated version and i was asked to ask a new question for updated version not update the question and i did but when i post here sometimes spaces fail .. so i have to redo it ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have a `user_table` containing your users, but it is almost empty. You then put the `user_id`, `user_email` and `user_pass` fields in the `student_table`, `teacher_table` and `management_table`, requiring you to gather them together like this:

```
   SELECT student_table.user_id ,student_table.user_pass
   FROM student_table
   WHERE student_table.user_email = :EMAIL
   UNION 
   SELECT teacher_table.user_id ,teacher_table.user_pass
   FROM teacher_table
   WHERE teacher_table.user_email = :EMAIL
   UNION 
   SELECT management_table.user_id,management_table.user_pass
   FROM management_table
   WHERE management_table.user_email = :EMAIL
```

This makes no sense. Why not put these fields in the `user_table`? The user table should contain all fields that are directly related to the user. That includes all the fields from the `user_status` table.

This would make for a much simpler database design, and shorter database queries. Keeping things simple will increase the security of the code because it will be easier to spot security holes.

This suggestion falls under the term: [database normalization](https://www.essentialsql.com/database-normalization/)

Comment: i have 14 different type of user each one have different limitation usage .. so i had a problem with unique id's when different types of user interact with eachother .. and someone recommended to do table for auto increment and type then add generated id with their limitation and credentials

Comment: @TaaLee An user is an user, regardless of the type or limitation. Each user should indeed have an unique id, and an auto increment field is a good way to achieve that.

Comment: so i keep the same amount of function but change structure of user table by removing email,pass and add them to users

Comment: @TaaLee: Yes, indeed, that is the idea.

Comment: @TaaLee: Please note that if you are already using the database, for real users, you might get conflicts: A student might have the same user id as a teacher. Of course that would create chaos. In that case you have to assign everyone a new, and unique, user id.

Comment: yeah i know thats why i have users table for auto increment then i get lastinsertedid() and added to usertype table

Comment: so i dont have to worry about the code anymore ? because ill take this as an example for every script

Comment: I tackled the biggest problem your code has, that doesn't mean the rest is fine. Security problems are often tiny things you forgot or did. It might be the way you handle errors. Since you're going to change the code quite drastically I cannot say it is fine. You do bind parameters to queries, use tokens, and hash passwords, those are all good things.